# unknown reason for segmentation fault

Tags: c++

I've tried just writing a program and no matter what, when using cout or cin the code always runs into a segmentation error.

examples:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    cout << "Hello World" << endl; //segmentation fault occurs here

    return 0;
}
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    int wallHeight = 0;
    int wallWidth = 0;
    int area = 0;
    double gallons = 0;

    cin >> wallHeight; //segmentation fault occurs here
    cin >> wallWidth;
    area = wallWidth * wallHeight;
    gallons = area / 350;

    cout << "Wall area : " << area << " square feet." << endl;
    cout << "Gallons needed : " << fixed << setprecision(2) << gallons << " gallons." << endl;
    cout << "Cans needed : " << round(gallons) << " cans.";

    return 0;
}
```

In the second block of code, if deleting the line where the segfault occurs, it will just move down to the next line until there are no more lines left.

I've tried looking online to see what the problem could be but no solution seems to be even related to whatever reason might be causing this.

Comment: Probably the installation or configuration of your compiler/libraries/ide is incorrect and it is linking with incompatible versions of (stanard) libraries

Comment: You seem to be in the DLL hell.

Comment: What does your build command look like?

Comment: OT: The expression `area / 350` is an all-integer operation, with an integer result. Assigning that integer result to a `double` variable will not add the already missing decimals.

Comment: It's possible to relate with kernel + CPU architecture on running machine and how do you compile your program. You should give more info about where is your program running (CPU + OS) and how  do you compile, link them.

Comment: What operating system are you using? It looks like you get a segmentation fault when using standard I-O, with iostream. If you try using stdio.h with `printf` and `scanf`, do the same problems occur? If you create a file, do you get the same problem (try `ifstream`, `ofstream`, `fopen` for reading with `fscanf` and `fopen` for writing with `fprintf`)?

Comment: The version of the header file you include `<iostream>` is incompatible with the version of standard library that you link with. So either your compiler is installed incorrectly, or your build is incorrect. To get this fixed you need to say a little about how you build your code, how you installed the compiler(s) you have etc etc,

Comment: And whether or not you followed the usual advice of "Just throw everything into the system path where it can collide with other tools using a different version of the library."

Comment: From information you have given, it is impossible to say (numerous possibilities).   Relevant information that *might* result in someone identifying the cause (or being able to ask more specific questions) includes (1)  what operating system/version  (2)  what toolchain  (IDE, compiler, linker, etc) [include version numbers if possible, describe how they were installed if you don't know.  If someone else (e.g. a sysadmin) did the installation, they have misconfigured)]   (3)  how are you building your program (through IDE, command line(s) to compile and/or link, etc)